# How do i mathematically apply a window function to a signal in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, discrete-mathematics

I am currently trying to make a plot of a windowed signal.  The plot is currently been made in latex, but  can't seem to recreate the plot generated in matlab in latex.

```
   %% Time specifications:
   Fs = 8000;                   % samples per second
   dt = 1/Fs;                   % seconds per sample
   StopTime = 60;             % seconds
   t = (0:dt:StopTime-dt)';     % seconds
   %% Sine wave:
   Fc = 60;                     % hertz
   x = sin(0.9*pi*t) + sin(0.42*pi*t);
   %x = cos(2*pi*Fc*t) + cos(2*pi*Fc*5*t)+ sin(2*pi*Fc*10*t);
   % Plot the signal versus time:
   figure;
   %plot(t,x);
   %xlabel('time (in seconds)');
   %title('Signal versus Time');
   %zoom xon;
   %%
   window = hamming(length(t),'periodic');
   %plot(window)
   windowed = x.*window; 
   plot(windowed)
```

This generates a plot like this

[image]

But when i tries to recreate the plot in **matlab**.. I get something way different.

What I am plotting is this :

```
w= sin(0.9*pi*t) + sin(0.42*pi*t)*0.54 - 0.46*( cos(360*t/600))
plot(w)
```

First part being the signal * window = windowed signal...
And what I get is this..

[image]

Why is this so different.. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it you have two errors in your expression. First you miss parenthesis around the window function and second you have the wrong period in the `cos` term. Try

```
 w = (sin(0.9*pi*t) + sin(0.42*pi*t)).*(0.54 - 0.46*( cos(2*pi*t/t(end))));
```